# UITapGestureRecognizer not changing contents of CollectionViewCell . Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view with lots of different pictures, and I want that when a picture is tapped, a border comes around it.

I made a custom cell, and a UICollectionViewCell with the imageView embedding in another view (which is the outline) for the pic. So I set up a UITapGestureRecognizer which works to get the index, but when I set the outer view to have a boder it doesn't work.

Here is my Cell:

```
import UIKit

class PicViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


    @IBOutlet weak var imageOutline: UIView!


}
```

This is in my UICollectionViewController:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PicViewCell

            // Configure the cell

     let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(sender:)))

            cell.imageOutline.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)




        return cell
```

Here is the method for the tapGesture

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tap")

        if let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: sender.location(in: self.collectionView)) {

            let cell = collectionView?.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PicViewCell

    cell.imageOutline.layer.borderWidth = 5


        } else {
            print("")
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `handleTap` routine, you're calling the wrong method to retrieve the cell.  You want [`cellForItem(at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618088-cellforitem) which will retrieve the existing cell or return `nil` if it isn't onscreen:

```
let cell = collectionView?.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PicViewCell
```

---

**Alternate solution**

If you are modifying the view you are tapping, you can access it as the `view` of the `sender`:

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let imageOutline = sender.view as? UIImageView {
        imageOutline.layer.borderWidth = 5
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** In both solutions, you should update your model when a cell is outlined so that if that cell scrolls off the screen and then back onto the screen, you can use that model data to set the outline for the cell correctly in your override of `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)`.

Comment: This works great thanks. But as you said, when I scroll back to the cell it doesn't stay outlined. I have updated the model, but its still not staying outlined. Thanks

Comment: In `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` after you dequeue the reusable cell, you need to set the layer borderWidth to 5 if your model says that cell has been tapped.